# custom taxonomies menu

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus

I have added 3 custom taxonomies. I would like to add the taxonomy Titles to my menu? I can add the terms but it is the actual names (Globale Nachhaltigkeit, Regionen and Medien) of the taxonomies that I want to add. Thanks in advance! This is how I have added my taxonomies.

```
function be_register_taxonomies() {
    $taxonomies = array(
        array(
            'slug'         => 'globale-nachhaltigkeit',
            'single_name'  => 'Globale Nachhaltigkeit',
            'plural_name'  => 'Globale Nachhaltigkeit',
            'post_type'    => 'post',


        ),
        array(
            'slug'         => 'regionen',
            'single_name'  => 'Region',
            'plural_name'  => 'Regionen',
            'post_type'    => 'post',


        ),
        array(
            'slug'         => 'medien',
            'single_name'  => 'medien',
            'plural_name'  => 'medien',
            'post_type'    => 'post',
        ),
    );
    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => $taxonomy['plural_name'],
            'singular_name' => $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'search_items' =>  'Search ' . $taxonomy['plural_name'],
            'all_items' => 'All ' . $taxonomy['plural_name'],
            'parent_item' => 'Parent ' . $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent ' . $taxonomy['single_name'] . ':',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit ' . $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'update_item' => 'Update ' . $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New ' . $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'new_item_name' => 'New ' . $taxonomy['single_name'] . ' Name',
            'menu_name' => $taxonomy['plural_name']

        );

        $rewrite = isset( $taxonomy['rewrite'] ) ? $taxonomy['rewrite'] : array( 'slug' => $taxonomy['slug'] );
        $hierarchical = isset( $taxonomy['hierarchical'] ) ? $taxonomy['hierarchical'] : true;

        register_taxonomy( $taxonomy['slug'], $taxonomy['post_type'], array(
            'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'rewrite' => $rewrite,
        ));
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'be_register_taxonomies' );
```

Comment: What would they link to? Taxonomies themselves don't have links in WordPress, just the terms. You could just add a custom link to `#` with the taxonomy name as the label if you just want a sort of heading.

Comment: I would like them to link to the archive page with all terms.

Comment: No such archive exists in WordPress. Archives are only ever of posts.

Comment: Sorry maybe i didn't explain this well.  At the moment I have a custom taxonomy media with 4 terms. I can get all posts with each term separately eg www.url.com/media/term1. Is it not possible to get all terms with www.url.com/media? at the moment it throws a 404. Thanks for you reply's.

Comment: It’s not possible, no. You could see all _posts_ of that post type at the post type archive URL, but the 404 you are describing is the expected behaviour for that URL.